# Clip an image with a shapefile in Google Earth Engine

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, intersection

I have an image collection in which I mapped a function to clip all images with a shapefile. The shapefile is a buffer of linear vector, and my goal is getting all areas that are outside the buffer. How should I do to achieve my main aim? Should I use not()? or xor?

I post below an example on what I'm doing:

```
var clip = function(image){ 

    return image.clip(buffer_shp);

}

var clc_col = collection.map(clip);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is modify the mask of the image, by removing parts that are covered by the geometry. So:

```js
// Construct example geometry
var buffered = lines.map(function (line) { return line.buffer(10000); });

// Construct binary image which is 1 everywhere but the geometry
var paintedInverse = ee.Image.constant(1).paint(buffered, 0);

// Apply to existing image's mask
var imageWithLinesCutOut = image.updateMask(image.mask().multiply(paintedInverse));

Map.addLayer(imageWithLinesCutOut);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/41b44271a771b9d978e67bd3618de4d3

[image: Example: SRTM image with a buffered line string removed]

Note: if the geometry is very complex, this can be made more efficient by, instead of buffering the lines, asking `paint()` to use a line width. The disadvantage of this approach is that the line width is in pixels, so the width of the region that is cut out of the image now depends on the resolution it's computed at (and is affected by variation in projection scale) — so it's harder to use correctly than the buffering.

```js
var paintedInverse = ee.Image.constant(1).paint(lines, 0, 30);
```

[image: Example: SRTM image with a line string removed, with square ends]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with 'difference' method before clipping with your function the region of interest. A complete example is showed below where it is also computed each land cover area from the first image in "COPERNICUS/CORINE/V20/100m" Image Collection by using an arbitrary rectangle in Europe with its respective buffer line shape (1000 m). It looks as follows:

[image]

Complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4ace2e331e3f2e36553146fc3e78f166) is:

```
var CLC = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/CORINE/V20/100m");

print(CLC);

var Rectangle = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-3.2278415693846974, 38.79336392652634],
          [-3.2278415693846974, 38.733398708728636],
          [-3.1179782881346974, 38.733398708728636],
          [-3.1179782881346974, 38.79336392652634]]], null, false);

var Line = ee.Geometry.LineString(
        [[-3.242604447802666, 38.75345967146791],
         [-3.20106239458001, 38.76577460808576],
         [-3.176686479052666, 38.756137012375795],
         [-3.1499073042479786, 38.77648152114054],
         [-3.0946323408690724, 38.77353728025261]]);

var buffer_shp = Line.buffer(1000);
var difference = Rectangle.difference(buffer_shp, 100);

var clip = function(image){ 

    return image.clip(difference);

};

var clc_col = CLC.map(clip);

print(clc_col);

var landCover_first = clc_col.first().select('landcover');

Map.centerObject(Rectangle);
Map.addLayer(Rectangle);
Map.addLayer(clc_col.first());
Map.addLayer(buffer_shp);
Map.addLayer(difference);

print('landCover_first', landCover_first);
print('Dataset covers (years) ', CLC.size());

//calculate coverage of each landcover classes

var counts = landCover_first.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry: difference,
  scale: 10
});

var LC_Counts = counts.get('landcover');

//create an dictionary object containing landcover types and their coverages
var LC_Count_Dict = ee.Dictionary(LC_Counts);

var landCoverClassVals = landCover_first.get('landcover_class_values');
var landCoverClassDefs = landCover_first.get('landcover_class_names');

var landCoverClassVals = ee.List(landCoverClassVals).map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.String(ee.Number(ele).int());
  
});

var LCDict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(landCoverClassVals, landCoverClassDefs);

print(LCDict);

var count_def = ee.Dictionary(LC_Counts).keys();
var count_val = ee.Dictionary(LC_Counts).values();

var count_paired = count_def.map(function (ele) {
  
  var idx = count_def.indexOf(ele);
  
  return [LCDict.get(ele), count_val.get(idx)];
  
}).flatten();

print(count_paired);
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, result was as follows. Image was clipped as expected and it was corroborated that areas were smaller that those computed with Rectangle as clip area.

[image]